# Bulk 301 redirect for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, redirect

I've amended the URLs for my custom post type from:

`url.com/jobs/job-name` to `url.com/jobs/job-location/job-name`

Problem is, because this isn't a standard rewrite wordpress doesn't do the 301 redirecting for you.

Does anyone know how I could do a 301 redirect for all custom posts to the new URL bearing in mind that job-location would be different depending on the post?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since `job-location` is a variable part - which content we do not know beforehand - it is not possible to easily solve this in a .htaccess redirect. You could however generate a list of posts with their old and new URI and place those redirects in the .htaccess - I would prefer it that way because then PHP is not needed at all.

If that is not an option, the following should work

```
add_action('wp_loaded', 'WPSE_redirect_jobs_new_url');
function WPSE_redirect_jobs_new_url(){
    // current request
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $parts = explode('/', $uri);
    if (substr($uri, 0, 6) !== '/jobs/' || count($parts) > 3) {
        // either URI does not start with jobs
        // or URI is already longer than /jobs/foo
        // so end early
        return;
    }

    $slug = array_pop($parts);
    $page = get_page_by_path($slug, OBJECT, 'MY_CPT');

    if (!$page instanceof WP_Post) {
        return;
    }

    // get new link
    $link = get_permalink($page->ID);

    wp_redirect($link, 301);
    exit;
});
```

Because WordPress has its own way of guessing redirects, it is important to use an early action. In my test, `wp_loaded` sufficed for this. Sadly, the global `$wp` is not fully populated by that time, so here I am checking the requested URI via `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead of `$wp->request`.

This of course relies on permalinks being set up for jobs as you wish them, otherwise `get_permalink()` will not yield the results you're looking for.